# Finding pixels within an ellipse(generated by Covariance Matrix)

Tags: c++, opencv

I generated the ellipse of a area of connected-components by covariance matrix:

```
    //initialize distribution of points
    int num = blob.size();
    float arr[num][2];
    for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        arr[i][1] = blob[i].first; //row index, y
        arr[i][0] = blob[i].second; //column index, x
    }
    //calculate covariance matrix
    cv::Mat mat = cv::Mat(num, 2, CV_32FC1, &arr);
    cv::Mat cov, mean;
    cv::calcCovarMatrix( mat, cov, mean, CV_COVAR_NORMAL | CV_COVAR_ROWS);
    cov = cov / (mat.rows - 1);
    //calculate eigen problem
    cv::Mat eigVec = cv::Mat(2, 2, CV_32FC1);
    cv::Mat eigVal = cv::Mat(1, 2, CV_32FC1);
    cv::eigen( cov, eigVal, eigVec);
    // cout << eigVec << endl;
    //calculate the major and minor axes
    float alpha = sqrt( eigVal.at<double>(0,0) ) * sqrt(chisquare_val);
    float beta = sqrt( eigVal.at<double>(0,1) ) * sqrt(chisquare_val);
    //calcualte the angle.
    double angle = atan2( eigVec.at<double>(0,1), eigVec.at<double>(0,0) ) * 180 / M_PI;

    return cv::RotatedRect( cv::Point2f(mean.at<double>(0,0), mean.at<double>(0,1)), 
        cv::Size2f(alpha, beta), angle);
```

and now, I need to calculate the distance of each pixel to the ellipse by the follow formula:

X= cos(θ)(x-xc) + sin(θ)(y-yc)

Y = -sin(θ)(x-xc) + cos(θ)(y-yc)

dist = (X/α)^2 + (Y/β)^2

where the θ is the angle of rotation, and xc, yc are the center coordinates,
α is the semi-major axes(always be the largest axes), and β is the semi-minor axes

Here is my implementation:

```
    double distance(cv::RotatedRect &ellipse, cv::Point &point)
{
    double center_x = ellipse.center.x;
    double center_y = ellipse.center.y;
    double alpha = ellipse.size.width / 2; //semi-major axes
    double beta = ellipse.size.height / 2; //semi-minor axes
    double angle = ellipse.angle; //rotation angle

    double p_x = point.x;
    double p_y = point.y;

    double new_x = (p_x - center_x) * cos(angle) + (p_y - center_y) * sin(angle);
    double new_y = (p_x - center_x) * (-sin(angle)) + (p_y - center_y) * cos(angle);

    double result = (pow(new_x, 2.0) / pow(alpha, 2.0)) + (pow( new_y, 2.0) / pow(beta, 2.0));
    return result;
}
```

I tested this code with images. It works well on a horizontal ellipse like:
[the grey area covers the points that within the ellipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRf4S.png)

but the code failed on a vertically ellipse and the output is like:[the gray area should cover the ellipse perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38dgU.png)

So, can someone tell me what is the problem and why the calculation of distance with a vertically ellipse is failed?

Comment: `double angle = ellipse.angle; //rotation angle`, `ellipse.angle` is in degree, while `angle` should be in radians. Try `double angle = ellipse.angle * CV_PI / 180.0;`